# How to add rows dynamically in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner to ReactJS and need to build a dynamic table for my work.

In that table, the user can add new lines and can also remove any existing lines.

The problem is, I don't know how to save the values that are typed into the new fields. My `onChange` function isn't working, I've done several tests, but I'm not able to save the entered values.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-surf-623uz?file=/src/App.js).

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong to save the entered values? Thank you in advance.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

import List from "./List/List";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    [
      {
        label: "Property Name",
        field: "propertyName",
        value: ""
      },
      {
        label: "Value",
        field: "value",
        value: ""
      }
    ]
  ]);

  const handleOnChange = (field) => (e) => {
    setData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [field]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const addRow = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      [
        {
          label: "Property Name",
          field: "propertyName",
          value: ""
        },
        {
          label: "Value",
          field: "value",
          value: ""
        }
      ]
    ]);
  };

  const removeRow = (index) => {
    const _data = [...data];
    _data.splice(index, 1);
    setData(_data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <List
        data={data}
        addRow={addRow}
        removeRow={removeRow}
        handleOnChange={handleOnChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";

import AddCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircle";
import RemoveCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircle";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

import "./styles.scss";

const List = ({ data, handleOnChange, addRow, removeRow }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map((items, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="content">
          <div className="content-row">
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <TextField
                key={index}
                label={item.label}
                value={item.value}
                onChange={handleOnChange(index)}
                variant="outlined"
              />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div>
            <AddCircleIcon onClick={addRow} />
            {data.length > 1 && (
              <RemoveCircleIcon onClick={() => removeRow(index)} />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good that you shared the code. There are several issues with your code. I have an updated code placed under this URL,

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mclean-hfyzs

Below are the problems,

1. Your data structure is an array of arrays and your onchange event doesn't respect that.
2. You have no property available [name/id] to identify a textbox when you change the value.

I had to add a name property to each textbox and design it like a 2D array so any textbox will have a unique name.

I had to map through the data array and find the node where I have to update the value and set the new value as the new state when any textbox changes.

I have added a console.log while adding a row so you can see the current state.